# ¿Cómo debo hacer para obtener la Geolocalizacion enviando una direccion por parámetro? Google Maps en Node

Tags: nodejs, google-maps, backend, google-api

Estoy intentando usar la libreria @googlemaps/google-maps-services-js, esta es la nueva version de la aterior @google/maps para node.

Parece que es diferente la sintaxis de la solicitud. Alguien sabe como se debe hacer?

La libreia anterior tenia ejemlos de como obtener las coorenadas pero la documentacion de esta nueva version no parece tener esa explicacion, o bien yo no estoy entendiendo.

[Enlace a la documentación de la libreía](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js)

```
import { Client } from "@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

import { Router } from "express";
import { User } from "../database.js";

const authRouter = Router();



authRouter.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password, fullName, address, phone, isDriver, plate, city } = req.body;
  
  if ( !email || !password || !fullName || !address || !phone, !city ) {
    return res.status(400).json({ ok: false, message: "Email and password are required" });
  }
  
  const googleMapsClient = new Client({ key: process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY })

  googleMapsClient
   .geocode({ address: 'Jose taberna 512, Las Varillas' })
   .then((response) => {
    const coordinates = response.data.results[0].geometry.location;
    const latitude = coordinates.lat;
    const longitude = coordinates.lng;

    console.log(`Coordenadas: ${latitude}, ${longitude}`);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.response.data.error_message);
  })


  try {
    const newUser = await User.create({
      email,
      password,
      fullName,
      address,
      city,
      phone,
      isDriver,
      plate
    })
    
    res.status(201).json({ ok: true, message: "User created successfully", newUser });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    res.status(500).json({ ok: false, message: "Internal server error" });
  }
})

export default authRouter;
```

---

Cuando hago la petición de registro la consola me muestra este mensaje

> Invalid request. Missing the 'address', 'components', 'latlng' or
> 'place_id' parameter.